# Putty-Python3-Jupyter notebook

Tags: virtual-machine, jupyter, putty

I need to run a Jupyter notebook 24/7 on a virtual environment. I've never done this before, and as a finance student I barely heard of this.
I have the putty connection, then the "something like cmd" opens, and HERE I am... (Really don't know where I am). There is also a virtual environment created (not by me), which has some capacity (like ram, storage, cpu, and stuff).

How do I open the jupyter notebook on the virtual environment?
Is there a way to do this or should I just delete all of this and run task scheduler?

Comment: If all you want is a always available Jupyter, use Google Colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PuTTY allows you to **SSH** to a server.

From this server's terminal session, you would need to run `jupyter server` (or `jupyter lab`). This would start the Jupyter Server/Lab *web server* on its default port. [Read the documentation on running (and securing) a public server](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/public-server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server).

Using the same hostname/IP that you used in PuTTY, copy it, and open `http://<that address>:<jupyter port>` in a browser window, and you should be presented with a Jupyter login page where you'd need to copy a token that is generated when Jupyter is started (assuming you've not configured any other authentication methods).

---

To get *Python code* to run constantly, it would be recommended to just use `cron` with a regular Python script, and not use a notebook file. Otherwise, you'd probably want to look at another CLI tool called [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-execute.html#execute-via-cli), along with `cron`

Comment: If I use cron or papermill, it wouldn't be affected if I power off/sleep my computer?

Comment: There's two computers here. Only the one running Putty can be turned off. This does not also turn off the remote server

Comment: I really appreciate your help man! thanks! Now I know where I'm standing :)